# English word for discarded cuttings in gardening

Tags: word-request

What is the word for discarded excess cuttings,plants,saplings? 
some time back I came across the word exclusively for it,and it is not garden waste or garbage.

Comment: Since *cuttings* can often refer to bits you intend to propagate new plants from, you might consider ***trimmings*** or ***clippings***.

Comment: In the US we refer to it as **yard waste**.

Comment: Perhaps "compost"?

Comment: Or maybe plant debris?

Comment: I don't know about a noun, but a specific verb for it is **to prune.**

Answer (score 1):

In many U.S. cities, material such as fallen leaves, extracted weeds, and pruned tree branches are all *yard waste.*  In many places, [such as Des Moines, Iowa,](https://www.mwatoday.com/news/yard-waste/no-yard-waste-in-garbage.aspx) they are required to put their yard waste in bins.

[image: Des Moines, Iowa Yard Waste Poster]

In some cities, such as Seattle, they also put *kitchen scraps* in the yard waste bins, which in Seattle are often called *compost bins.*

The terms are a little loose, though. [In Santa Monica, California,](https://www.smgov.net/uploadedImages/Departments/Public_Works/Solid_Waste/Organics.jpg?n=8453) for instance, they put their *food scraps* and their *yard debris* into a *Green Cart.*

[image: Picture of a "green organics cart"]

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several words:

- [Offcuts](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/offcut)
- [Cuttings](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cutting)
- [Trimmings](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trimmings)

However with grass, hedges, and flowers, all little plants I'd use **trimmings**. With trees and saplings I'd use **offcuts**. **Cuttings** mostly refers to bits you intend to propagate new plants from.